# How to use React.forwardRef to expose child's methods?

Tags: reactjs, polymer, web-component, lit-element

**What I try to do:**

I converted my react component A to litElement `<web-component-b />`. Is it a way to use A's internal methods?

```
e.g. 
const myRef = useRef() 
<web-component-b ref={myRef}/>
myRef.current.innerMethod().
```

Below is pseudo code that I play around. I want to expose C3 component's method1 and method2, but when running is ref is always null.

```
export default TestComponent = React.forwardRef(props, ref) => {
<Parent ref={ref}>
  <C1 ref={ref}>
    <C2 ref={ref}>
      <C3 ref={ref}> -> method1 and method that I want to use
        <C4>
          <C5>
});


// start to use
const testComponentRef = useRef(null);
<TestComponent ref={testComponentRef} />

testComponentRef.method1();
testComponentRef.method2();
```

Comment: what is setter and getter? Are you trying to expose component methods?

Comment: This sounds like it goes against the one-way data flow philosophy of react. React context might be a better call here.

Comment: @Chris, yes try to expose component methods

Comment: @net.uk.sweet, I just want to expose C3's methods

Comment: So why not pass them down the hierarchy as callback functions in component props?

Comment: @net.uk.sweet because it is like a embed / re-usable component.

Comment: Can you post a more concrete example as I'm struggling to understand what you want?

Comment: @net.uk.sweet, I updated it a bit see if help